# Custom dialog with DatePicker has issue in layout

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-datepicker

I have custom layout for a `DialogFragment` with `DatePicker` and some label, as shown below. But I can't remove whitefield to the right, any suggestions? Also, how can I unselect a day in calendar (when have no initial date)? API 26

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/pickerReminderDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/Grey300"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:padding="@dimen/indent_small"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@color/TextInverse"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal
        android:text="@string/dialogDateNote"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the container LinearLayout width and height to match parent. 
Set date picker width to match parent.